# Replacing letters

Tags: xetex

How to make it so that following latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
n
\end{document}
```

produces a pdf with letter `n` replaced by `m`?

From [How to automatically replace one letter with another before rendering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319646/how-to-automatically-replace-one-letter-with-another-before-rendering) I see one option is to

```
\catcode`\X=\active
\def  X{Y}
```

But that don't work with letter `n`

```
\catcode`\n=\active
\def  n{m}
```

Comment: The ```\catcode`\n=\active``` doesn't work if you put it into the preamble, because `\begin{document}` contains an `n` (and you have just changed the meaning of `n`). It does work if you make the definition *inside* the `document` environment and additionally open a group around it and the text it should affect (to avoid messing with `\end{document}`). But you still won't be able to use any commands with `n` in their name within that group.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213947/35864

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to do that? As surprising as it may sound, (La)TeX is not extremely good at manipulating the raw *text* you input into the document. So I would usually try to avoid having to do that as much as possible. (Many editors have search and replace or RegEx features to do the replacement directly in the document.)

Answer (score 2):

With luatex you could add a substituation rule to the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua
{
 fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "mysubs",
    type = "substitution",
    data =
      {
          ["n"] = {"m"},
      },
  }
}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[RawFeature=+mysubs;]

\begin{document}
n m o p 
\end{document}
```

With xelatex something similar is possible with TECkit mappings (such mappings are e.g. used to map `--` to an endash.).

Answer (score 1):

It can work only if you scope limit the catcode change, since any macro with an "n" in its name (such as `\end`) will break the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Nsubon{\catcode`\n=\active}
\newcommand\Nsuboff{\catcode`\n=11 }
{\Nsubon\gdef n{m}}
\begin{document}
\Nsubon jklmn
and when I am done...
\Nsuboff

{\Nsubon Alternately, scope the code in a group}
\end{document}
```

[image]