# Conditional string replacements in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, strings, lua

I want to process whole tex file content with string replacements using lua. The following  are the conditions

1. F, G, H should be replaced by P, Q, R respectively.
2. However if they aren't followed by a, e, i, o, u then replace them by Px, Qx, Rx respectively.
3. However if they are followed by letter Y then replace them by S, T, U.

So there are 3 conditions. 
If tex file is

```
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document} 
    FGH\\
    FaGaHeF\\
    FYGYHY
    \end{document}
```

Then it should output to

```
PxQxRx
PQRPx
STU
```

How to write lua code to do this?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the document won't contain words such as `Figure`, `Garage`, and `Hotel`? Or should they be converted to `Pgure`, `Qrage`, and `Rtel`, respectively? Please advise.

Comment: Figure, Garage and Hotel should be converted to Pgure, Qrage and Rtel respectively.

Comment: Isn't this question, by any chance, related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498342/134574)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your write-up of the substitution rules isn't very clear. I've interpreted them as follows:

1. If the letters `F`, `G`, and `H` are followed by a lowercase vowel (i.e., one of `aeiou`), the uppercase-lowercase letter pair should be replaced with `P`, `Q`, and `R`, respectively.
2. If the letters `F`, `G`, and `H` are followed by the uppercase letter `Y`, they (including the letter `Y`) should be replaced with `S`, `T`, and `U`, respectively.
3. If neither case 1 nor case 2 applies, the letters `F`, `G`, and `H` should be replaced with `Px`, `Qx`, and `Rx`, respectively.
4. All other material in the document should *not* be be affected by the preceding three substitution rules.

As long as the body of your document doesn't contain macros or environments whose names contain the letters `F`, `G`, and/or `H`, you can simply "turn on" the Lua function -- more precisely, assign it to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, making the function act like a preprocessor on the input stream -- by running `\fghOn` after `\begin{document}`. It will then keep on running until it gets to `\end{document}`. The Lua function can be switched off via `\fghOff`. If you need to perform the substitution on just one string at a time, you could use the macro `\fghSub` -- cf. its use in the final row of the following working example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' and '\luastringN' macros
\luaexec{ % set up Lua function called 'fhg_sub':
```

```lua
function fgh_sub ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "F[aeiou]" , "P")
   s = s:gsub ( "G[aeiou]" , "Q")
   s = s:gsub ( "H[aeiou]" , "R")
   s = s:gsub ( "FY" , "S"  )
   s = s:gsub ( "GY" , "T"  )
   s = s:gsub ( "HY" , "U"  )
   s = s:gsub ( "F"  , "Px" )
   s = s:gsub ( "G"  , "Qx" )
   s = s:gsub ( "H"  , "Rx" )
   return s
end
```

```tex
}

%% Three LaTeX macros to interface with the Lua function:
\newcommand\fghOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", fgh_sub, "fgh_sub" )}}
\newcommand\fghOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "fgh_sub" )}}
\newcommand\fghSub[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(fgh_sub(\luastringN{#1}))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\fghOn % assign 'fgy_sub' Lua function to preprocessor stack
FGH
FaGaHeF
FYGYHY
\fghOff % remove Lua function from preprocessor stack
Figure, Garage, Hotel
\fghSub{Figure, Garage, Hotel} % run the function on a one-off basis
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your interpretation of substitutions is absolutely right.

Comment: @user61681 - No, this solution will not work under XeLaTeX.

Comment: Is it possible to modify code to replace say FY by \textbf{S} i.e. FY is to be replaced by boldface S. Does this need complete change of code or modification is possible?

Comment: @user61681 - Just change `”S”` to `”\\textbf{S}”`. (Note the doubling of the backslash character.)

Comment: Thanks. It works.