# Polytonic Greek in LaTeX with Arno: multiple diacritics on one letter

Tags: accents, greek

I am trying to paste in a text in Unicode polytonic Greek where there are multiple accents on a single character.  As discussed in [Multiple diacritics on one character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159291/multiple-diacritics-on-one-character), it is totally feasible to create multiple diacritics on one character with LaTeX, but my problem is slightly different: is there a way, perhaps using Lua, to paste in polytonic Greek pre-composed, and have the correct output be produced?  (The alternative is hand recomposing each glyph with two accents, which is quite annoying) I am using Arno, as purchased from Adobe, which should be capable of outputting polytonic Greek, but is failing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\begin{document}
 ἐπῐ́λογος
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The combination of breve with an acute accent isn’t a standard requirement in fonts supporting polytonic Greek.

Comment: @Thérèse yes—it's strange, and the "practical" (i.e., easy) answer may be to simply find and replace the characters with double accents out (although that may be a bit annoying because iota with breve and acute is not a precomposed unicode glyph).  However, I suspect it may be common enough for people who have to paste Ancient Greek texts glossed and edited by others (my case), that there's some utility in asking

Comment: @Thérèse My instinct, which may be totally off, is to try to write some luacode that will substitute these unusual glyphs with a LaTeX friendly composition stacking as appropriate; no idea if that's the right track, but I'll try it

Comment: “… iota with breve and acute is not a precomposed unicode glyph” sounds to me like an issue better handled by a font that can do “mark to mark” features.

Comment: The issue here isn't about the combination with the breve or the pre composed input. The issue is that the used font "Arno Pro" does not contain a composable acute accent (codepoint U+0301 does not exist). If you use a font which supports this accent (e.g. Noto Serif), then it will work. You should add the `[Script=Greek]` option after `\setmainfont` though to get proper handling for greek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be relatively easy using code lifted from this answer ([Conditional string replacements in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500372/conditional-string-replacements-in-lualatex)); just a neat bit of LuaCode renders this working nicely:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\combinedaccent}[2]{%
\leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \char#1\relax\cr
      \noalign{\vskip -1.3ex}
      \noalign{\vskip 0.1ex}
      #2\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\iotafix}{\combinedaccent{180}{ῐ}}   % oxys

\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' and '\luastringN' macros
\luaexec{ % set up Lua function called 'fhg_sub':
function iota_sub ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "ῐ́" , "{\\iotafix}")
   return s
end
}
\newcommand\iotaOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", iota_sub, "iota_sub" )}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\begin{document}\iotaOn
  ἐπῐ́λογος
\end{document}
```

Produces the beautiful:
[image: epilogue]